# $Tf=f'$ unbounded linear operator.

Tags: functional-analysis

How to prove that $$T:C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$$ is an unbounded linear operator, where $$Tf=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}.$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any function $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$, write 
$$f_k(x) = \frac{1}{k^n} f(kx),\ \ \ k\in \mathbb N.$$
Note that $\| f\|_{L^2} = \|f_k\|_{L^2}$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$.

Let $\eta$ be a smooth function compactly supported in $B(0,1)$ with $\|\eta\|_{L^2} = 1$. Then $\|\eta_k\|_{L^2} = 1$ for all $k$. But 
$$\frac{\partial \eta_k}{\partial x^j} (x) = \frac{1}{k^{n-1}} \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x^j } (kx) = k \left( \frac{1}{k^n}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x^j } (kx)  \right) = k \left(\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x^j}\right)_k (x)\Rightarrow \| T\eta_k\|_{L^2} = k \| T\eta\|_{L^2} \to \infty$$

as $k\to \infty$. Thus $T$ is unbounded.